# dialogflow with node.js how do you swtich intents

Tags: node.js, dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I have an intent that has a required parameter and a fulfilment. When you answer it takes you to my node.js application which currently looks like this:

```
app.intent(QUESTIONS_INTENT, (conv, params) => {
  let data = conv.data;

  let categoryId = data.categoryId;
  let formulas = data.formulas;
  let options = {
    'method': 'PUT',
    'url': apiUrl + 'questions/filter',
    'body': {
      categoryId: categoryId,
      organisationId: organisation,
      formulas: formulas
    },
    'json': true
  };


  return request(options).then(response => {

    // We need to change how we get these
    var questionText = params.questions;
    var questions = response.filter(item => item.text === questionText);

    data.questions = questions;
    conv.ask(questions[0].text);
    conv.contexts.set('colour');
  }, error => {
    conv.ask(JSON.stringify(error));
  });
})
```

Currently it gets the `questionText` and finds the question that matches what you said. What I want it to do is to swap to a new intent. I have tried by `conv.contexts.set('colour')` but that doesn't appear to work.

I have an intent setup with input context as "Colour" so I would expect that when my fulfilment completes, it should swap to that intent, but it doesn't.

Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure that you have a `colour` intent setup in DialogFlow that will handle the input from the user and respond to them. The question should be asked *after* you set the context.

```
return request(options).then(response => {

    // We need to change how we get these
    var questionText = params.questions;
    var questions = response.filter(item => item.text === questionText);

    data.questions = questions;

    // Sets the context to colour.
    conv.contexts.set('colour', 1);

    // Now that the context is in control you'll be able to ask a question.
    conv.ask(questions[0].text);
```

You'll also want to provide a lifespan after the context arg. This will make the context active for that many prompts, in the example above I set it for one so your question context will only be active for that specific response.

```
conv.contexts.set('colour', 1);
```

Comment: This is what I ended up doing and it did work. But it doesn't work for followup intents. Any idea what I have to do there?

Comment: Followup intents primarily get handled in DialogFlow (https://dialogflow.com/docs/contexts/follow-up-intents), if you want to increase the lifespan of a context you can change the integer value.